# Introducing probability measures in $\left(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\right)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm reading Shiryaev's Probability and I'm in the section where he introduces the probability measure in   $\left(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\right)$. Now he uses a difference operator $$ \Delta_{a_j,b_j} F(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = F(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{j-1}, b_j, \ldots x_n) - F(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{j-1}, a_j, \ldots x_n),  $$ where $F(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is a distribution function, meaning that for $\Delta_{a_j,b_j}$ you're working with coordinates $x_j$ only while the rest is fixed.
He states the following theorem without proof:

$$ P(a, b] = \Delta_{a_1,b_2} \ldots \Delta_{a_n,b_n} F(x_1, \ldots, x_n),$$ for $(a,b]= (a_1, b_1] \times \ldots \times(a_n, b_n] $.

I'm trying to prove it for the bidimensional case, meaning that:

$$P(a,b] = F(b_1, b_2) - F(a_1, b_2) + F(a_1, a_2) - F(b_1, a_2)$$

But I'm clueless on where to start this and I'd like some advice or reference for this proof. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2-dimensional identity should read
$$
P(a,b] = F(b_1,b_2)-F(a_1,b_2)-F(b_1,a_2)+F(a_1,a_2).
$$
Let $Q(c,d):=\{(x,y): x\le c, y\le  d\}$. I'd start by drawing a figure showing how the rectangle $(a,b]$ can be represented as
$$
[Q(b_1,b_2)\setminus Q(a_1,b_2)]\cup[Q(b_1,a_2)\setminus Q(a_1,a_2)].
$$
(This is a disjoint union.)

Comment: Thanks, I edited my original question. I'll try starting with that!! ;)